# Prisma problem inserting into autogenerated int ID field: integer out of range for type int4

Tags: sql, postgresql, prisma, cockroachdb

```
model Comment {
  id        Int             @id @default(autoincrement())
  cid       String      
  bid       String
  author    AppProfile      @relation(fields: [bid], references: [bid])
  comment   String
  created   DateTime        @default(now())
}
```

```
const results = await prisma.comment.create({
  data: {
    cid: req.body.cid,
    comment: req.body.comment,
    bid: appProfile.bid,
  },
});
```

```
prisma:query INSERT INTO "public"."Comment" ("cid","bid","comment","created") VALUES ($1,$2,$3,$4) RETURNING "public"."Comment"."id"
prisma:query ROLLBACK
error - PrismaClientUnknownRequestError:
Invalid `prisma.comment.create()` invocation:


Error occurred during query execution:
ConnectorError(ConnectorError { user_facing_error: None, kind: QueryError(Error { kind: Db, cause: Some(DbError { severity: "ERROR", parsed_severity: Some(Error), code: SqlState(E22003), message: "integer out of range for type int4", detail: None, hint: None, position: None, where_: None, schema: None, table: None, column: None, datatype: None, constraint: None, file: Some("eval.go"), line: Some(65), routine: Some("init") }) }) })
    at RequestHandler.handleRequestError (/Users/jmalicke/Projects/muf/dev/repos/muf/bubbles-serverless/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/index.js:34314:13)
    at RequestHandler.request (/Users/jmalicke/Projects/muf/dev/repos/muf/bubbles-serverless/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/index.js:34293:12)
    at async PrismaClient._request (/Users/jmalicke/Projects/muf/dev/repos/muf/bubbles-serverless/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/index.js:35273:16)
    at async comment (webpack-internal:///(api)/./pages/api/comment/index.ts:26:25) {
  clientVersion: '4.6.1',
  page: '/api/comment'
}
```

This is strange because the id column is an Int and should be default autoincrementing. The error message complains about int4. If I look in the database the only int4 column is the id field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your users are too active, if there is more than 2.147.483.647 comment ids, the Int id has reach it max value

You can convert it to BigInt like:

`id      BigInt    @id @default(autoincrement())`

But the best is maybe to use uuid like:

`id      String   @id @unique @default(uuid())`

```
Int max =   2.147.483.647
BigInt max = 9.223.372.036.854.775.807
UUID max = 3.4*10^38 or 340000000000000000000000000000000000000 (thanks to Belayer)
```

Comment: FYI: not that it really matters but max UUID= ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff (approximately 3.4*10^38 or 340000000000000000000000000000000000000)

Answer (score 2):

First, make sure your provider in schema.prisma is set to "cockroachdb" if you're using CockroachDB.

For reference, CockroachDB [only supports autoincrement on BigInt](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/database-connectors/cockroachdb), while for Int's, [CockroachDB uses sequence()](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-schema-reference#sequence)